# What is datatype of Model Parameter in spring when no data is passed in Jquery Ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

What is the data type of Model Parameter when nothing is passed for the model parameter with that name using Jquery Ajax Call?

Consider the following Jquery Ajax Post operation:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: {'A':'a','B':'b'},
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data){
        if(data.success==true){
            alert('success');
        }else if(data.success==false){
            alert('Failed');
        }
    }
});
```

and following Spring annotation based controller definition

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "dummy" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody HashMap<Object, Object> createDiagram(@ModelAttribute(value = "A") Object a,@ModelAttribute(value = "B") Object b,@ModelAttribute(value = "C") Object c)
    {
boolean object=(c instanceof Object); // returns true;
boolean string=(c instanceof String); //returns false

//TODO: Need to check if c is null or if the value of 'C' was actually passed in Ajax Call
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your example, you're trying to send an anonymous javascript object to your server using POST method.

In order to actually bind data using `@ModelAttribute` annotation, when a request comes into the controller, you need to the next steps:

Within your HTML from, you'll need to use the `name` attribute within your input tags, text area tags, and other form tags. each "element" tag inside your form should match to a field inside an object you're trying to bind using that name attribute.

for example:

let's say you have a class User.java, and you're trying to bind data to it:

```
public class User {

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private String email;
}
```

so your form should include let's say 3 input tags with matching name attribute:

```
<input type="text" name="firstName" />
<input type="text" name="lastName" />
<input type="text" name="email" />
```

Now, your binding can actually take place like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String goHome(@ModelAttribute User)
{
}
```

This was the binding problem.

Now for the **ajax**, first you'll need to get the HTML form's data. let's say you have an id of myForm on your HTML form, then:

```
var myData = $("#myForm").serialize();
```

now, under data you should send myData, like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: myData,
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
success: function(data){
    if(data.success==true){
        alert('success');
    }else if(data.success==false){
        alert('Failed');
    }
}
```

});

```
return false;
```

The URL should be the full HTTP address to the server, something like this:

`http://localhost:8080/your_app/your_route`

Don't forget after the jquery ajax call to immediately return false, or any other value. that is the proper way to complete an ajax call.

The ajax success method is expecting to any kind of text as a reply from Spring's Controller (more accurately from dispatcher servlet).

So within your controller don't forget to use the `@ResponseBody` annotation, that will tell dispatcher servlet not try to resolve a view, but returns the value of the method as a part of HTML body.

So if any string or JSON that you'll return, they'll be sent in the body of HTTP response.